# UISegmentControl doesn't refresh UILabel connected to UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uilabel, uipickerview, uisegmentedcontrol, uipicker

I am a big beginner in Xcode and have encountered a problem while building my app. My app consists of an UILabel, UIPickerView and UISegmentControl. I wanted my app to show a different value in UILabel every time the user changes the selected row in UIPickerView. At first I only had one set of values to show in UILabel but eventually added a second set. I added UISegmentControl in order for the user to be able to switch between these two sets. Here is an example of my "if statements"

```
- (void)pickerView: (UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (row == 0 && segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {


    pickLabel.text=@"100 PPM";
}

else if (row == 0 && segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {


    pickLabel.text=@"110 PPM";
}

else if (row == 1 && segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {


    pickLabel.text=@"95 PPM";
}

else if (row == 1 && segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {


    pickLabel.text=@"105 PPM";
}
```

The problem is that the value in UILabel only changes when the selected row in UIPickerView is changed and not when the segment control is changed. For an example when I change the segment control index, UILabel does not change until I switch to a different row in the UIPicker. I want to make an IBAction that forces the UILabel to change when the segment control index is changed. Than I will connect my IBAction to the UISegmentControl with "value changed".
I need some code to put into the IBAction. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)pickerView: (UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
```

get executed when you change the picker value alone .When changing the segment you have to invoke a method and do the same here in this method

Try this

declare

```
NSInteger selectedRowInpicker;
```

and use

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged
{
    if (selectedRowInpicker == 0 && segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {


        pickLabel.text=@"100 PPM";
    }

    else if (selectedRowInpicker == 0 && segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {


        pickLabel.text=@"110 PPM";
    }

    else if (selectedRowInpicker == 1 && segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {


        pickLabel.text=@"95 PPM";
    }

    else if (selectedRowInpicker == 1 && segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {


        pickLabel.text=@"105 PPM";
    }
}


- (void)pickerView: (UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    selectedRowInpicker =row;
    [self valueChanged];
}
```

**connect the valueChanged to the segment action "value changed"**

Comment: take care of the initial condition in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me... The application does run and everything but I get a semantic issue. "incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') from 'NSInteger' (aka 'int'); take the address with &"
I get this notification at every "selectedRowInpicker = row;" and "row" is highlighted yellow.

Comment: NSInteger doesn't need  * ,Updated the answer ,Try it use `NSInteger selectedRowInpicker;`

Answer (score 0):

you should register an event for UISegmentedControl as well.

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

now create a method like:

```
-(void) valueChanged:(UISegmetedControl *)control
{
    [self modifyLabel];
}

- (void)pickerView: (UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [self modifyLabel];
}

-(void) modifyLabel
{
//Based on picker and segmented controller, update the label
}
```